# Catch unhandled exception in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, unhandled-exception

In WCF, is there an event or method that catches unhandled exceptions, or do I need to put a try/catch in any method?

Comment: Why do you want to catch unhandled exceptions? What do you want to do with them? Do you want to do this in a client or in a service?

Comment: One goal could be to capture/log the exception to a standard log file outside the WCF Diagnostics trace.

Comment: Did you find it out so far? I am trying also to do something similar without success

Answer (score 7):

Yes, create a class that implements the [`IErrorHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) interface:

> Allows an implementer to control the fault message returned to the caller and optionally perform custom error processing such as logging.

Comment: It is very complicated, can you give a sample? 
and, need it to server-side. not client. 

Thanks

Comment: Note to late comers to this answer: IErrorHandler implementations are not utilized in WCF Data Services. In your DataService<T>, override HandleException.

If you are self hosting, also consider handling:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException

Answer (score 0):

You should do Inner and outer TRY/Catch Blocks.

So the first method starts with Try

Then if anything is thrown within another method it defaults to your generic catch in the method that is in the exposed method to return a value to the client.

I always use logging in my catch blocks to tell an admin what went wrong but I aways have the outer catch return a value of something like "Please Except our Appogies the WCF.Blah service has failed. Please review the server logs for complete details"

This way you have error handling, logging and nice messages to your clients..

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        try
        { 
            return somemethod(value);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingHelper.Log(ex);
            return "Please Except our Appogies the WCF.Blah service has failed. Please review the server logs for complete details";
        }
    }
```

Comment: i need more than 1 wcf Service mathod. 
Is there anything similar to "onerror" event in global.asa, in ASP.NET that catch all unhandled exception?